# How to build a svn project that depends on other svn project

Tags: svn, jenkins, ant, multiple-projects

I would like to try jenkins for CI of my project !

For building my project, I need 3 others SVN modules (that contains other project).

for example, my project architecture look like :

```
- https://scm-svn/myproject/build
   - build subproject 1
   - build subproject 2
   - build subproject 3

- https://scm-svn/myproject/common
   - common subproject 1
   - common subproject 2
   - common subproject 3

- https://scm-svn/myproject/server
   - server subproject 1
   - server subproject 2

- https://scm-svn/mainproject/server
   - main project server 1
```

**main project server 1** contains a build.xml ant file that build the whole project (with the modules) when they are in the same workspace (like eclipse does).

In jenkins, When I use svn module, after each new module, the workspace is cleaned !

So I try to use "clone workspace plugin", I've created a new project each svn module and create a workspace.zip for each projects.

But in the **mainproject** configuration, how can I configure it to copy/past the others subproject workspace into  mainproject's workspace ?

In this way I will be able to execute an ant task in build step for lunching my build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is an open issue related to exporting using the subversion plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1304

You can decide not to use the Subversion plugin and execute "svn export.... command".

Another idea might be to exclude the .svn folder from the checkout (if it will not checkout the .svn folder it'll mimic the same behavior as export)

Good luck!

Comment: It do not work, each time jenkins execute new svn command, jenkins also clean current workspace !

I need all the svn repo to be checkouted in the same workspace

Comment: Can you add a print screen of your Jenkins SCM configuration? the default behavior is not to clean but use the update method. It'll be easier to view the job configuration to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You can find a screenshoot at this url : http://zupimages.net/up/16/21/d74z.png   (In fact, there 4 differents svn url)

Comment: If you're checking out several repositories to the same local module directory it'll clean the workspace every time. if all configurations for your repositories are checking out to "./" please try what I answered and specify a module folder to each repository. I tried it locally on my system and it worked.

Comment: I can specify a module folder for each repo, it will checkout without error, but what I need is : all those repo to be checkouted in the same directory (like eclipse does), otherwise my ant script will not work

Comment: unfortunately you can only have one .svn folder per workspace, and you can't have several folders that contain the meta-data to be combined. What you're talking about is not CHECKOUT but EXPORT. unfortunately there is an open issue related to it : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1304. If you can't find a way to work around it (point the script to different locations instead of the root folder) I would suggest to not use the Subversion plugin and to run svn export .... command.

Comment: Another idea might be to exclude the .svn folder from the checkout and to hope it'll work (if it will not checkout the .svn folder it'll mimic the same behavior as export) - not sure it'll work but it's a minute to test.

Comment: can post a reply ? I'll mark it as "answer my question"

Comment: Thanks - glad it worked out - I've edited my answer.